# Repeated parameters in overloaded constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, variadic-functions

I want to write a class in Scala that takes an arbitrary number of bytes or booleans like this one

```scala
class Bytes(data: Byte*) {
  def this(data: Boolean*) = this {
    val res: Array[Byte] = convBools2Bytes(data)

    res: _*
  }

  // […]
}
```

where `convBools2Bytes` is a function that converts an `Array[Boolean]` to an `Array[Byte]`:

```scala
def convBools2Bytes(data: Array[Boolean]): Array[Byte]
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

```
[error] Bytes.scala:5: no `: _*' annotation allowed here
[error] (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
[error]     res: _*
[error]        ^
```

As far as I understand it, the `res: _*` statement turns the `Array[Byte]` into a list of repeated parameters (as explained in Section 8.8 in [“Programming in Scala”, 2nd Ed.](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)).

Why is there such an error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: I just inserted the `convBools2Bytes` for making things clear. Didn’t think about it. In the real implementation, there’s a lot of code in this block. So in the example it really makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the compiler says, you may only use that in arguments to vararg parameters. You're trying to have the block return an expanded vararg list, that isn't allowed.
If you'd like to use the block then:

```
this({
  val res: Array[Byte] = convBools2Bytes(data)
  res
}: _*)
```

Otherwise this should be fine as well

```
this(convBools2Bytes(data): _*)
```

But you'll run into another problem, erasure will cause both to have the same signature and prevent compilation.
I think you'd be better off without overloading anyways

Comment: I thought Arrays are special case and not going to be erased

Comment: Usually yes but methods taking varargs get compiled to ones taking scala.collection.Seq it seems.

Comment: Thanks, Kaito. And you’re right with your last statement: Now I get a  `double definition` error. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: I edited changed the main constructor to take an `Array[Byte]` directly.

Comment: A trick I found in the standard libraries is to specify an extra element explicitly, e. g.: def foo(x: Int, xs: Int*)

Comment: @pvorb I would make a factory method in the `Bytes` companion object called something like `fromBooleans`